# Lenis.js easing option for smooth scroll works but has syntax error

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver, easing

I use [lenis.js](https://github.com/studio-freight/lenis) for smooth scrolling which works well, see [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/d1j65vrg/10/). However my Dreamweaver shows syntax error which is the easing option: easing: (t) => (t === 1 ? 1 : 1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t)).

The whole code:

```
const lenis = new Lenis({
    duration: 1.2,
    easing: (t) => (t === 1 ? 1 : 1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t)),
    direction: "vertical",
    gestureDirection: "vertical",
    smooth: true,
    smoothTouch: false,
    touchMultiplier: 2,
});

function raf(time) {
    lenis.raf(time);
    requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}

requestAnimationFrame(raf);
```

I would like to know if this line is correct, or from where this error comes from, or why Dreamweaver shows it as an error. As I am completely blind in this easing with math.pow question, please try to explain as simpliest possible.

Comment: Doesn't dreamweaver show any error details/type etc ? Does the error go away if you replace that line with `easing: function(t){return (t === 1 ? 1 : 1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t))},`

Comment: @Gabriele Petrioli - yes, it is ! Dreamweaver does not show anymore this error. Please write an answer to able to accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Dreamweaver version you use (*or the linter it uses, or a linter rule*), does not support/allow the arrow function syntax (*at least not in the context of your code*).

Try using a regular function like this

```
const lenis = new Lenis({
    duration: 1.2,
    easing: function(t){return (t === 1 ? 1 : 1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t))},
    direction: "vertical",
    gestureDirection: "vertical",
    smooth: true,
    smoothTouch: false,
    touchMultiplier: 2,
});
```

---

Also check if you can update the DW version, its linter or edit the linter rules.

Perhaps [Use Lint code in Adobe Dreamweaver to detect errors](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/linting-code.html) could be of use.